# ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make my update function work. I have included txtPassword and txtConfirmPassword textboxes. The two textboxes must match before the update itself however I get this error:

```
ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized
```

How can I make it work? Here are my codes:

```
protected void btnUpdateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    if (txtPassword.Text == "")
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
            "LastName=@LastName, Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, City=@City, ZipCode=@ZipCode, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
            "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
    }
    else
    {
        if (txtConfirmPassword != txtPassword)
        {
            pnlInconsistent.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password=@Password, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
                "LastName=@LastName, Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, City=@City, ZipCode=@ZipCode, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
                "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLN.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStreet.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Municipality", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMunicipality.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtZipCode.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContact.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        if (fuImage.HasFile)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "~/images/" + fuImage.FileName;
            fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fuImage.FileName));
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = imgAvatar.ImageUrl;
        }


        if (txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
                Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        }


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        GetProfileInfo();

        pnlUpdated.Visible = true;
        Helper.AddLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), "Update", "Updated Profile Information");
        GetProfileInfo();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that if this `if (txtConfirmPassword != txtPassword)` is true the update query will execute always and the `commandText`parameter won't be set as the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`isn't part of the `else`statement, which it probably should be. I'm guessing that you want to stop execution of the query if the password and txtPassword and txtConfirmPassword doesn't match, but I don't see that happening.

Also this if-check seems redundant as it only executes if the txtPassword isn't empty:

```
if (txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
                Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code also executes `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line for the case when `txtConfirmPassword != txtPassword` where `CommandText` is not initialized.

Either add a `return;` for this case just after `pnlInconsistent.Visible = true;`:

```
if (txtConfirmPassword != txtPassword)
{
    pnlInconsistent.Visible = true;
    return;
}
```

or wrap all those `cmd.Parameters.Add()` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in your nested `else`:

```
else
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password=@Password, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " + "LastName=@LastName, Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, City=@City, ZipCode=@ZipCode, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " + "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFN.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLN.Text;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStreet.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Municipality", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMunicipality.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtZipCode.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContact.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    if (fuImage.HasFile)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "~/images/" + fuImage.FileName;
        fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fuImage.FileName));
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = imgAvatar.ImageUrl;
    }


    if (txtPassword.Text != "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
            Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
    }


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GetProfileInfo();

    pnlUpdated.Visible = true;
    Helper.AddLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), "Update", "Updated Profile Information");
    GetProfileInfo();
}
```